# How can Close wxDialog in wxWidget?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I spent many hours studying the problem How to Close app what i build form wxDialog 
I create two button OK and Exit, when i press Exit or sign [X] signal of App then i issue this error

Error image: [image]

```
  // The Queue of Event Table

    BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(AutoPokemonDlg, wxDialog)
    EVT_BUTTON(wxID_OK, AutoPokemonDlg::OnOK)
    EVT_BUTTON(wxID_EXIT, AutoPokemonDlg::OnExit)
    EVT_CLOSE(AutoPokemonDlg::OnCloseWindow)
    END_EVENT_TABLE()


    // I create Event Handler

    void AutoPokemonDlg::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
    {
        Close(true);
    }

    void AutoPokemonDlg::OnCloseWindow(wxCloseEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
    {
        Destroy();
    }

    and main Window, i use wxDialog to inherit my subclass is AutoPikachuDlg
    ////AutoPokemonDlg.h
    class AutoPokemonDlg : public wxDialog
    {
    public:
        // Constructor
        AutoPokemonDlg(wxWindow* parent, const wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
        ~AutoPokemonDlg();
        // Event handlers
        void OnOK(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event));
        void OnCloseWindow(wxCloseEvent& event);

    protected:
    private:
        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
    };

    //////AutoPokemonDlg.cpp
    AutoPokemonDlg::AutoPokemonDlg(wxWindow* parent, const wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
        : wxDialog(parent, id, title, pos, size)
    {
    //...
    };
```

Comment: are you using modal or modeless dialog?

Comment: #Igor  i wanna create a modal dialog.

Comment: you should call `EndModal()`. Check the appropriate documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show how do you create and show your `AutoPokemonDlg`, but if you do it on stack, as recommended, e.g. like this:

```
void SomeEventHandler(wxEvent&) {
    AutoPokemonDlg dialog(...);
    dialog.ShowModal();
}
```

then your code will result in calling `delete &dialog` which is clearly wrong, as this is not a heap pointer. This happens because you call `Destroy()` from your `OnCloseWindow()` handler -- it can't be used for modal dialogs for exactly this reason.

The simplest fix is to just remove your `OnCloseWindow()` handler entirely, it's usually unnecessary as the dialog will close anyhow if it has any buttons that can be used for closing it, such as `wxID_OK` or `wxID_CANCEL`. If it doesn't close on its own for you, it might be because you do something strange in your `OnCloseWindow::OnOk()` (which you don't show neither). If you want it to close your dialog, call `EndModal()` to do it from there.